# Disable CSRF hidden input in Thymeleaf

Tags: spring-security, thymeleaf

I have a simple search input:

```
<form>
  <input name="search" />
</form>
```

As soon as I add a `th:action`, Thymeleaf adds a hidden CSRF input field, even though I don't need it here.

Is there a way to disable this behavior for this given form?

Answer (score 0):

You can add

```
<csrf disabled="true"/>
```

to your spring-security.xml file, because the csrf protection is enable default.

So your config file may like :

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="false">
    <form-login
            login-page="/login"
            default-target-url="/index"
            login-processing-url="/login"
            password-parameter="password"
            username-parameter="username"
            authentication-failure-handler-ref="authenticationFailureHandler"
    <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/logout" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
    <csrf disabled="true"/>
</http>
```

Comment: But as far as I understand, this changes the behavior of the entire app. Is there also a way to only change the form?

Comment: You should to implements RequestDataValueProcessor( Spring Security use the CsrfRequestDataValueProcessor as the default implements) and processAction method.In that method you can decide what action you want to auto add csrf token, after you do this you should also extends OncePerRequestFilter, because the CsrfFilter will interceptor your request .